# Convert epoch time format in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

We are able to see a Timestamp column upon splitting the JTL file generated after a load test.

We want to convert the Timestamp (Which is currently in epoch format) to a more understandable and readable format such as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

Please help us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy these properties from `jmeter.properties` file and add to `user.properties` file

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Results file configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Timestamp format - this only affects CSV output files
# legitimate values: none, ms, or a format suitable for SimpleDateFormat
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

just comment or uncomment the line `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` for getting epoch time or human readable timestamp format.

Need to restart the jmeter after updating the `user.properties` file